# How to enable login/logout event logging at keycloak with event listener config at Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

from UI, I have enabled login/logout events to log at keycloak server.

[image: event config page]

still, at the server log, the below error message is present:

```
11:30:31,159 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0083: Event listener 'LOGOUT' registered, but provider not found
11:30:31,159 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0083: Event listener 'LOGIN_ERROR' registered, but provider not found
11:30:31,161 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) KC-SERVICES0083: Event listener 'LOGIN' registered, but provider not found
```

which provider is needed to log those events properly?

I have deployed keycloak as a service at Kubernetes. below is the deployment configuration file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: REALM
          value: "app-example"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: "postgres"
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: "postgresdb"
        - name: DB_USER
          value: "postgresadmin"
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: "admin123"
        - name: DB_SCHEMA
          value: "keycloak"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
          value: "INFO" 
        - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
          value: "/opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements/realm.json"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements
          name: elements
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: elements
        configMap:
          name: keycloak-elements
      initContainers:
      - name: init-postgres
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup postgres; do echo waiting for postgres; sleep 2; done;']
```

Let me know, changes needed to enable those events logs at keycloak server

Comment: Did you check [this docs](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/configuration.html) ?

Comment: @PjoterS currently, at our application external identity provider is not enabled and keycloak is used to authenticate REST API. so without enabling the identity provider, event listener won't work?

Comment: Have you tried to switch log level (KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL) to DEBUG?

Comment: @RadimGöth Yes, but finally i have changed the standalone.xml file to enable event-logging